# Access 2007 DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim Currency

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, export-to-csv

In Access 2007 I am using the DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim to export a table as a .csv file type to a specific location on our network.  The transfer itself seems to be working ok and my table that is being transferred is in the correct format with two places after the decimal, even if zero cents.  However, on the Export Specifications I see no column for field types and the resulting .csv file has stripped the trailing zeros that were present in the starting table.

Is there a VBA that I can insert into my (Public Function tsfrPR() DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "exportspecs", "table", "\network\location\filename.csv", False End Function) to retain this formatting in the original table?  Thanks!

Have pictures of what these screens look like, but need 10 rep to post, lol

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i ve not enough rep points to comment but if you have formatting issues i would recommend to export a query and not the table directly. You can format the fields in the query, maybe even as text. Maybe there is a better way to solve the problem with formatting but that' s the way i do it.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up finding my own answer.  Thanks Chroni, I did check into exporting as a query.

My answer was to requery the table and use the format FUNCTION (not property) and set it to a "Fixed" format.

Works like a charm now and even running thru my macro.